# Assistance with understanding how to simplify/reduce expressions.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Peace to all. I recently started a College Algebra and Trig course. It's been a long while since I sat in a math class (over 13yrs) but I enjoy every second of it.  Little by little it's coming back but the rust is still there. As a class when we went over the problems and examples of simplifying and reducing rational expressions I got a handle on the problems but when I went to do a practice HW problem, I didn't understand.  The expression is $(27x^2-162x)/6x$. I reduced the expression to $(9x^2-54x)/2x$ (dividing the coefficients by $3$) but then gotten stuck.  I googled and seen that the answer is [$(9(x-6))/2$](https://www.symbolab.com/solver?or=gms&query=(27x%5E2-162x)%2F(6x)) and seen that a different approach was taken (that method wasn't shown in my class).  Was the way  I approached the answer "wrong"?

I understand that there are different ways to solve mathematical equations, so I'm not trying to get caught up in that but trying to clearly understand how to solve the problem.

Comment: What you have done thus far is correct.  Try factoring the numerator.  Once you do so, you may see how to reduce your expression to the stated answer.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You began with the right approach; you just did not do enough of it. Let's begin by factoring the numerator and denominator and then follow through with cancelling terms.

$$\frac{27x^2-162x}{6x}
  =\frac{27 x (x - 6)}{3x(2)}
  =\frac{9 (x - 6)}{2}$$

BTW, I find [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+27x%5E2-162x%29) easier to use than the link that you offered in your post. Have fun.

Comment: I appreciate your response and the link. Thank you.